# How can I view 10-bit H264 (hi10p) videos in GStreamer video players like Totem?

Tags: vlc

I have a 10-bit H264 video, but I can't play it in Totem or VLC. I tried recompiling libx264 with 10-bit support after removing libx264-116, but it doesn't seem to work. VLC does not use GStreamer, but seems to also use libx264.

[image]

Comment: Any chance you can add a link to an example of such a video?

Comment: Have you tried installing libavcodec-extra-52 from Medibuntu repository? 
http://medibuntu.org/repository.php

Comment: fossfreedom: I don't have a small video file. What I have here is a 169MB file.

Comment: Pisu: I tried it, but still didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [mplayer](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/news.html)? According to MPlayer 1.0rc3 release - it support 10-bit H264 videos. And for a nice GUI for mplayer, you could checkout [smplayer](http://smplayer.sourceforge.net)

Comment: I currently use MPlayer2 and SMPlayer, but Totem (and GStreamer) are faster in my netbook and my desktop. I can't even play videos in SMPlayer in my netbook - I need to move the videos to my desktop to view them (though a lot of times, the video gets unsynchronized with the audio). Other videos play fine in Totem on my netbook.

Comment: @ArnelA.Borja Have you tried using **testing** repository or compiling from source? sometimes the current repositories aren't that up-to-date or some bug fixed upstream might not have synced up in the repositories yet.

Comment: I use Ubuntu not Debian, but I use the Precise Alpha 2 (which is based on Debian Testing). I also tried to compile from source before.

Answer (score 0):

You need to recompile `gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg` with your `libx264` compatible to 10 bits h264 codec. Or compile VLC with it. Remember to use the correct `--prefix` in `./configure`. I recommend using VLC in this case.

Comment: I tried to recompile the packages from the Ubuntu repositories but it still doesn't work. Maybe there's something missing? I used the x264 (added 10-bits option), libav and gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg source packages.

Answer (score 0):

Install Ubuntu Restricted Extras.

Comment: Still didn't work...

Answer (score 0):

VLC 1.2.x (from the nightlies) and Mplayer2 supports h264 10 bits depth.

Comment: I'm currently using Mplayer2 and VLC from the Ubuntu PPA play 10-bit h264 videos, but they are slower compared to Totem (especially unstable VLC, the video is unviewable, while the video in Mplayer2 always gets unsynchronized with the audio).